# Synchronous promise-based methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make so that some object's methods, that have a promise-based function calls inside worked synchronously.

Here, for example, we have a `worker` object. It has some prototyped methods that calls promise-based functions. For testing purposes I have created a `DummyPromise` function that returns a promise to output a message after certain time.

```
var Promise = require("promise");

var worker = function(param_a, param_b) {
    this.param_a = param_a;
    this.param_b = param_b;
};

worker.prototype.job1 = function() {
    DummyPromise(1, 5000);
};

worker.prototype.job2 = function() {
    DummyPromise(2, 3000);
};

worker.prototype.job3 = function() {
    DummyPromise(3, 1000);
};

function DummyPromise(jobId, timeout) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(jobId, "finished.");
        }, timeout);
    });
}

var w = new worker("aa", "bb");
w.job1();
w.job2();
w.job3();
```

If I run the code as is it will output something like:

```
3 finished.
2 finished.
1 finished.
```

..because all 3 methods are executed immediately, and the output depends on timeout.

Now the idea is to rewrite `job1`, `job2` and `job3` functions so that they become synchronous and in result I get:

```
1 finished
2 finished
3 finished
```

Now the solution to use something like `async.mapSeries` is not a variant, because I do not have to run just 3 methods one by one - instead I will eventually have some complicated logic in the program that requires to run and rerun different jobs and I need to make sure that each job is executed synchronously to avoid callback hell and spaghetti code in final program.

Eventual program environment would be node.js, if it matters. No Babel.

**Note** Maybe a [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) or [coroutines](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) could be a solution? Looks very promising.

Comment: Promises by their very nature are asynchronous, so you can't run them synchronously. What you probably want to do is run them sequentially. In that case `co` is probably the best solution (as `async/await` it not yet available in node).

Comment: "Now the idea is to rewrite job1, job2 and job3 functions so that they become synchronous " If you say your functions are async by their nature neither you could nor you should make them sync.

Comment: they are async now because they have promises inside (promise-based calls of methods from other libraries). The idea is to wrap necessary functionality to a synchronous methods.

Comment: May be you can call jobs in chain? `w.job1().then(job2).then(job3)`? The only thing you'll need for this is to return a promise in each `job`

Comment: no, unfortunately chain is not an option also - there will be a lot of `if-else` in my code, calling individual methods based on state and conditions

Comment: @kaytrance You can't. Generally speaking async as effect "infects" everything it touches.  Once a part of your code (even a third party code) is async the rest of the code relaying on it becomes async. You can't simply and reliably get rid of this effect.

Comment: Synchronous code returns *right now*. *Asynchronous* code finishes *sometime later*. You cannot unify these two things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only good solution I have managed to find was to use `async/await` module from [here](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait).

It now works just ideal.

Answer (score -1):

Through chaining the promises,  you can easily do this.

How the chaining works ? promise1 is executed immediate, promise2 is depend on promise1  and  so on.  hope the the code explains it.

NOTE: If the DummyPromise  interns does some async/promise stuff,  you can chain those to!

```
var Promise = require("promise");

var worker = function(param_a, param_b) {
    this.param_a = param_a;
    this.param_b = param_b;
    this.promise = Promise.resolve(); //Starting point, resolved promise
};

worker.prototype.job1 = function() {
    //chaining starts here
    this.promise = this.promise.then(function() {
        return DummyPromise(1, 5000);
    });
};

worker.prototype.job2 = function() {
    //now this promise is pending on result from previous one
    this.promise = this.promise.then(function() {
        return DummyPromise(2, 3000);
    });
};

worker.prototype.job3 = function() {
    this.promise = this.promise.then(function() {
        return DummyPromise(3, 1000);
    });
};

function DummyPromise(jobId, timeout) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(jobId, "finished.");
            resolve();
        }, timeout);
    });
}

var w = new worker("aa", "bb");
w.job1();
w.job2();
w.job3();
```